# How can I troubleshoot a NextAuth middleware issue that logs me out after signing in?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to login using NextAuth and the middleware keeps on kicking me out even after I signin. It takes me back to the sign page..

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions, DefaultSession } from "next-auth";
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import EmailProvider from "next-auth/providers/email";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: {
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, user }) => ({
      ...session,
      user: {
        ...session.user,
        id: user.id,
      },
    }),
    signIn: async ({ user }) => {
      return "/dashboard";
    },
    redirect: async ({ baseUrl }) => {
      return `${baseUrl}/api/auth/signin`;
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

This is my middlware. I want to protect the dashboard page only

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard"] };
```

I honestly don't see anything wrong with my code. I'm trying to signin using Google.

I tried remove the matchers restriction and it works without the matcher but them the dashboard is not longer protective